# Remove/destroy Nicescroll bar from element (integration with JQuery MultiSelect)

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile, nicescroll, jquery-ui-multiselect

I have added a `NiceScroll` bar to a div:

```
$("#div-name").niceScroll();
```

How can I remove/destroy it?

I have tried the following, but it doesn't work:

```
$("#div-name").getNiceScroll().stop();
```

The following is also not a solution:

```
$("#div-name").getNiceScroll().resize();
$("#div-name").getNiceScroll().hide();
```

**EDIT: I found the problem! When adding `NiceScroll` to divs that are automatically generated by the [JQuery Multiselect](https://github.com/ehynds/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget) plugin, on iPad I have some visualization problems on other `NiceScroll` divs. So it's probably an issue relating to the integration of the two plugins(`NiceScroll` and `JQuery` `MultiSelect`).**

Answer (score 23):

But this works `$("#ID").getNiceScroll().remove();`

Try to execute in console on nicescroll demo page: `$("#boxscroll2").getNiceScroll().remove()` and you'll see that first div *This is a simple scrollable DIV* will change from nicescroll scrollbars to native browser ones.

Comment: Yes you are right.
I will investigate where is the problem, sure it's caused by nicescroll but probably there is one conflict with other plugin or code.
For you i must delete the question?

Comment: Nope, do not remove it. Maybe someone else will face this problem and will find answer here.

Comment: @Diego87 like I found, after half hour effort, landed here :)